# Verify whether an input is an number and whether a number has been repeated or not?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, loops

i know there have been a few questions on this game, but mine has a few more instructions so it makes it a bit more difficult. I am almost done, I just have a couple more things to complete. my code is as follows:

```
- (NSString *)output {

    NSMutableString *resultOutput = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    int secretNumber= arc4random_uniform(10);
    int numberChosen;
    int attempt=0;

    NSMutableArray<NSNumber*> *myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    printf("Guess a Number\n");
    printf("\n");
    scanf("%d", &numberChosen);

    while (numberChosen != secretNumber) {

        if (numberChosen < secretNumber) {
            printf("Too Low\n");
            printf("Guess Again\n");
            scanf("%d", &numberChosen);
            attempt++;
        }
        else if (numberChosen > secretNumber) {
            printf("Too high\n");
            printf("Guess Again\n");
            scanf("%d", &numberChosen);
            attempt++;
        }
        else if (numberChosen ==secretNumber) {
            attempt++;
            break;
        }

        [myArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:numberChosen]];
    }
    if (numberChosen == secretNumber) {
        NSLog(@"\nGood job, you guessed in %i tries", attempt);

    }

    return resultOutput;
}
```

My output should be:

```
Guess a number:
> 12
Too Low!
Guess a number:
> 65
Too High!
Guess a number:
> 65
Already Guessed!
Guess a number:
> asdf
Not a number! Try again!
Guess a number:
> 42
You got it! You took 3 attempts!
```

I got as far as creating the loop that verifies whether you're higher or lower and how many tries it took. What I am stuck on now is verifying whether the input was a letter, and if so to display on the console that it is not valid. I am also having trouble with verifying whether a number has already been inputted and displaying a message saying that this number has already been guessed.

Help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: This is exactly the same as your previous https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54016066/difficult-number-guessing-game. Do not do that. If your question doesn't get the attention you desire, edit it to form a better question.

Comment: Sorry! I wasn't getting much help on the one posted from before so I thought I'd ask again.

Comment: Yes, and that's exactly what I'm saying you must not do - or if you do, _delete_ the previous question.

Comment: Also I gave you a very useful comment on the previous question: did you think about what I said? If you did, you should have been able to solve that part of the problem.

Comment: Matt, thanks for the documentation, but I already read through it, still could not figure out what I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the return value of `scanf`.

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/scanf.3.html)

> RETURN VALUE
>
> This function returns the number of input items assigned. This can be
>        fewer than provided for, or even zero, in the event of a matching failure.
>        **Zero indicates that, although there was input available, no conversions
>        were assigned; typically this is due to an invalid input character,
>        such as an alphabetic character for a `%d' conversion**.  The value EOF is
>        returned if an input failure occurs before any conversion such as an end-of-file
>        occurs.  If an error or end-of-file occurs after conversion has
>        begun, the number of conversions which were successfully completed is
>        returned.

Edit:

If you use the return value you have to empty the buffer in case letters have been entered.

This is an implementation of all conditions. Rather than an array a set is used to avoid duplicates:

```
int secretNumber = arc4random_uniform(10);
int numberChosen = 0;
int returnValue = -1;
int attempt = 0;

NSMutableSet<NSNumber*> *set = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];

printf("Guess a Number\n");
printf("\n");

while (numberChosen != secretNumber) {
    returnValue = scanf("%d", &numberChosen);
    attempt++;
    if (numberChosen == secretNumber) {
        break;
    }
    else if ([set containsObject:@(numberChosen)]) {
        printf("Already Guessed!\n");
    }
    else if (returnValue == 0) {
        printf("Not a number!\n");
        int c;
        while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
    }
    else if (numberChosen < secretNumber) {
        printf("Too Low\n");
        [set addObject:@(numberChosen)];
    }
    else if (numberChosen > secretNumber) {
        printf("Too high\n");
        [set addObject:@(numberChosen)];
    }
    printf("Guess Again\n");
    printf("\n");

}
NSLog(@"\nGood job, you guessed in %i tries", attempt);
```

Comment: But my input needs to be a number and if I enter a letter I get stuck in a continuous loop, I don't get a response that says 0.

Comment: Thanks again, vadian. One adjustment, I had to move the NSLog at the bottom up to where it says if (numberChosen == secretNumber)

Answer (score 0):

Where possible, use Objective-C types so you can take advantage of built-in classes such as a number formatter to parse input and an NSArray to record prior guesses.  Use methods to organize the code so the game algorithm is clear.

```
@property(strong,nonatomic) NSMutableArray *priorGuesses;

- (NSNumber *)promptForNumber {
    char cstring[256];

    NSLog(@"Guess a Number\n");
    scanf("%s", cstring);         // note that input exceeding 256 chars will write past this buffer

    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithCString:cstring encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    return [formatter numberFromString:string];
}

- (BOOL)isUnique:(NSNumber *)number {
    if ([self.priorGuesses containsObject:number]) return NO;
    [self.priorGuesses addObject:number];
    return YES;
}

- (void)game {
    BOOL gameOn = YES;
    self.priorGuesses = [NSMutableArray array];

    NSInteger secretNumber= arc4random_uniform(10);
    NSNumber *guess = @(-1);

    while (gameOn) {
        guess = [self promptForNumber];
        if (guess && [self isUnique:guess]) {
            NSInteger guessInt = [guess intValue];
            if (guessInt == secretNumber) {
                // notice that there's no need to count attempts in a separate var
                NSLog(@"Good job, you guessed in %ld tries", self.priorGuesses.count);
                gameOn = NO;
            } else if (guessInt > secretNumber) {
                NSLog(@"Too high");
            } else {  // by implication, guessInt < secretNumber
                NSLog(@"Too low");
            }
        } else {
            NSLog((guess)? @"Already guessed\n" : @"Not a number\n");
        }
    }
}
```